# How to implement the flood-fill algorithm in android?

Tags: android, algorithm, native-code, flood-fill

How to implement the Flood-fill algorithm in android.But the code was written in c language.could we implement the algorithm in android.is there any open source code available or any website tutorial link

Comment: i have a White image view in android.how to fill the color using this algorthim'Flood-fill"

Comment: ndk can be used for using c  on Android http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm for flood fill is a very simple recursive one.

```
//Initialize i and j to the place to start
floodFill(int arr[][], target_color, replace_color)
{
    if(arr[i][j] == replace_color)
        return;
    replace(target_color, replace_color);
    floodFill(int[i+1][j], target_color, replace_color);
    floodFill(int[i][j+1], target_color, replace_color);
    floodFill(int[i-1][j], target_color, replace_color);
    floodFill(int[i][j-1], target_color, replace_color);
}
```

Flood Fill using queue. Use a asynctask to flood fill.

Parameters

1. bitamp to be filled
2. point where the user touches (x,y cordinates)
3. Color of pixel where use touches
4. Color to be replaced.

   ```
   public class FloodFill {

   public void floodFill(Bitmap  image, Point node, int targetColor,
       int replacementColor) {
   int width = image.getWidth();
   int height = image.getHeight();
   int target = targetColor;
   int replacement = replacementColor;
   if (target != replacement) {
       Queue<Point> queue = new LinkedList<Point>();
       do {
           int x = node.x;
           int y = node.y;
           while (x > 0 && image.getPixel(x - 1, y) == target) {
               x--;
           }
           boolean spanUp = false;
           boolean spanDown = false;
           while (x < width && image.getPixel(x, y) == target) {
               image.setPixel(x, y, replacement);
               if (!spanUp && y > 0 && image.getPixel(x, y - 1) == target) {
                   queue.add(new Point(x, y - 1));
                   spanUp = true;
               } else if (spanUp && y > 0
                       && image.getPixel(x, y - 1) != target) {
                   spanUp = false;
               }
               if (!spanDown && y < height - 1
                       && image.getPixel(x, y + 1) == target) {
                   queue.add(new Point(x, y + 1));
                   spanDown = true;
               } else if (spanDown && y < height - 1
                       && image.getPixel(x, y + 1) != target) {
                   spanDown = false;
               }
               x++;
           }
       } while ((node = queue.poll()) != null);
   }
     }
        }
   ```

Comment: i need to implement in android program is there any example littlebit?

Comment: I'd expect StackOverflowError after few recursions ;) Better would be non-recursive algo.